# How to move a VM within VMs and Templates view using PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am reorganizing the Host and Clusters and VMs and Templates in vCenter. I want to do this automatically using a script. I can move the VMs out of resource pools and into new ones no problem using the Move-VM command, however I also need to move the VMs into new folders in the VMs and Templates view as well. I can create the folder I want to move it to using this command:

```
$newVMFolder = (Get-View (Get-View -ViewType Datacenter -Filter @{"name"=$vmFolderLocation}).vmfolder).CreateFolder($newFolderName)
```

Then when I use this command:

```
Move-VM -VM $vm -Destination $newVMFolder
```

I get this error, 'Cannot convert the "Folder-group-..." value of type "VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference" to type 
"VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.Inventory.VIContainer".'

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using the CreateFolder method instead of using the 'New-Folder' cmdlet? The output from 'New-Folder' should give you the proper object type for the 'Move-VM' command.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way to create a folder in the VM and Templates view than above, but I just added:

```
$newVMFolder = Get-Folder -Name $newFolderName -Type VM
```

after I create the folder.

Now $newVMFolder is an inventory type instead of a managed object so

```
Move-VM -VM $vm -Destination $newVMFolder
```

now moves it into that folder.

Comment: Adding to this, you should also be able to make use of the 'InventoryLocation' parameter that's been added to PowerCLI 6.5.2 so that you can move the VMs to a resource pool and a folder all in the same command.